# isset() returns true from a string variable accessed as an array with any key

Tags: php

I face a problem like this:

```
$area="Dhaka";

isset($area); //returns true which is OK

isset($area['division']); //returns true why?

// actually, any array key of area returns true

isset($area['ANY_KEY']);//this is my question 1

isset($area['division']['zilla');//now it returns false. 

//as I know it should returns false but why previous one was true.
```

Now if I do this:

```
$area['division'] = "Dhaka";
isset($area); // returns true which is OK
isset($area['division']); // returns true it's also OK
isset($area['ANY_KEY']); // returns false. I also expect this

isset($area['division']['ANY_KEY']); // returns true why? question #2
```

Basically both of my questions are the same.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I just had this bug. Took me 30 minutes to figure out. What a pain. Seems to be fixed in at least PHP 5.5.25 though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with every programming language in existence, a string is stored as an array of characters.

If I did:

```
$area = "Dhaka";
echo $area[0];
```

It would return `D`.

I could also echo the whole string by doing:

```
echo $area[0].$area[1].$area[2].$area[3].$area[4];
```

[PHP will also type juggle a string into `0`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) when passed in a manner that accepts only integers.

So by doing:

```
echo $area['division'];
```

You would essentially be doing:

```
echo $area[0];
```

and again, getting `D`.

That's why `isset($area['division'])` returns a `true` value.

Why doesn't `$area['foo']['bar']` (aka `$area[0][0]`) work? Because `$area` is only a single-dimension array.

The best approach to handle this problem when you're working with a variable that could either be a string or an array is to test with `is_array()` before trying to treat your variable as an array:

```
is_array($area) && isset($area['division'])
```

Comment: we know it's an array

Answer (score 9):

PHP lets you treat a string as an array:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo[1]; // outputs 'a'
```

So

```
$area['division']
```

will be parsed/executed as

```
$area[0];
```

(the keys cannot be strings, since it's not REALLY an array, so PHP type-converts your `division` string by its convert-to-int rules, and gives `0`), and evaluate to the letter `D` in Dhaka, which is obviously set.

Comment: `array keys cannot be strings`??? In this scenario it won't accept strings, but array keys certainly can be declared as strings in PHP.

Comment: That's why I gave you the solution I did. Because it doesn't matter what PHP accepts as a key even though we know we can use strings as references to array elements. That's why my solution is a good workaround.

Comment: sorry. bad phrasing. if you're dealing with a string, then the array notation access cannot use strings for the keys. fixed up the answer a bit.

Comment: No sweat :) @xendi PHP degrades the behaviour and type juggles into integers when working with a string being treated as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a solution rather than explaining why isset isn't going to work properly.

You want to check if an array element is set based on it's index string. Here's how I might do it:

```
function isset_by_strkey($KeyStr,$Ar)
{
    if(array_key_exists($KeyStr,$Ar))
    {
        if(strlen($Ar[$KeyStr]) > 0 || is_numeric($Ar[$KeyStr] !== FALSE)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}

isset_by_strkey('ANY_KEY',$area); // will return false if ANY_KEY is not set in $area array and true if it is.
```

Comment: This fixes the problem and can be easily adapted for multidimensional arrays like in your example.

Comment: To do that just add another string parameter to the function and add a conditional statement to check for 2 parameters that then checks the extra dimension using the extra string as a key.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access a linear array in php is

```
// string treated as an linear array 
$string= "roni" ;
echo $string{0} . $string{1} . $string{2} . $string{3};

// output = roni
```

Answer (score -1):

It is expected behaviour.

[PHP Documentation covers this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

You can try empty() instead.

Comment: `!empty($area['division'])` would still return true since `$area['division'] === 'D'`

Answer (score -1):

If it is returning true for keys that do not exist there's nothing you can do; however, you can make sure that it doesn't have a negative effect on your code. Just use array_key_exists() and then perform isset() on the array element.

Edit: In fact, using array_key_exists() you shouldn't even need isset if it is misbehaving just use something like strlen() or check the value type if array_key_exists returns true.

The point is, rather than just saying isset($Ar['something']) do:

```
if(array_key_exists('something',$Ar) )
```

and if necessary check the value length or type. If you need to check the array exists before that of course use isset() or is_array() on just the array itself.

Comment: In the other person's answer it was explained that this behavior is expected. Considering that (or even not) this solution seems to be what you would want to use.

Comment: `array_key_exists` will throw a warning when you pass a string as a second argument, so no, you don't want to use something that throws warnings on you.

Comment: In the example in the manual you will see: array_key_exists('first', $search_array). Why would you pass a string as the second argument?

Comment: Because that's what OP is testing with, a string. `$area = "Dhaka";`

Comment: You wouldn't pass a string as the second argument.

Comment: The question is essentially about accessing a string as an array and why php casts a string to an integer on some occasions. Using array_key_exists (which is btw. slower than isset) is not a real answer to that question in my oppinion as the original value in the ops question is a string and not an array (which array_key_exists would require)

Comment: He's trying to check if an array element is set by referencing it's string key. That's exactly what this method I posted is doing.

Comment: No, he is asking why isset returns true if he tries to access a string using array syntax using a string key.

Comment: I'm not concerned with why isset isn't a good solution. I'm concerned with getting his code to work.